# I'm still having a confusion at saying whether the integral exists or not! Is it always a requirement for the mash size to go zero?

Tags: real-analysis

Okay, It's hard to explain.

Assume $f$ is a continuous function on set $D \subset R^2$ With no zero areas or anything. I want to evaluate $$\int\int_{D}f$$ By the way, Let $N_k$ be a grid which is a sequence of grids $N_1, N_2, N_3, ..., N_k$

My question is, is being continuous a sufficient condition here? In my textbook, before applying the reimann sum we always state the following.

"Since $\lim_{k-> \infty}d(N_k)=0$ and $f$ is continuous, we can conclude that integral exists."

Why do we state $\lim_{k-> \infty}d(N_k)=0$? If $f$ is continuous, then wouldn't this imply that the integral exists? Do we state $\lim_{k-> \infty}d(N_k)=0$ to make sure that this grid eventuallyy converges to the area? If the latter is the case, then why? Can there be grids that has mash size diverge?

Comment: You are not quoting your textbook properly. What is the complete statement? What book are you reading? In which section?

Comment: If $f$ is continuous and $D$ is bounded, the integral exists.  Existence of the integral has nothing to do with the grids.  But if you want to approximate the integral by Riemann sums over grids, you'll need
the integral to exist (otherwise there's nothing to approximate), and you'll also need the mesh size to go to $0$.